# PDF annotations in separate file, git mergeable

Tags: linux, android, git, pdf-viewer, ascii

I am looking for a PDF viewer that allows annotations that are stored in an separate file, ideally in an ASCII format that works well when merged by git.
Ideally the viewer works on Android, Linux and Mac's.

Comment: Is a pure Android solution acceptable (in the hope other answers cover the other two systems)? If so, I might have something nice (my personal favorite).

Comment: Yes, an android solution would help.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, I can warmly recommend **[Moon+ Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp)** (for PDF, you will need the paid version). (One of) the fastest PDF readers, well supported – I use it myself for years. As a side-effect, you'll have the same features for many other eBook formats.

Annotations (and highlights) are saved into the PDF file directly (so you see them with other readers as well). Additionally, they are saved into a local database which can be exported into a text file (which Git should be able to deal with fine).

[image: Annotations in Moon+] [image: Net Libraries]
<sup>Highlights and Annotations, Network libraries in *Moon+* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Plenty of other goodies in there, e.g. direct access to many net libraries, day/night modes, and more. Currently it's USD 5, but Seany often makes discount actions (I wouldn't wonder if there'd be an XMas action soon).

Comment: Moon+ looks interesting. Does the pro version allow free drawings and notes overlayed onto the pdf?

Comment: I've never needed that, so I didn't test. Oh wait, yes: free drawings I've seen from a proof-reader of one of my books, so yes. And notes = Annotations? // You could pick the free version to find out. It doesn't support PDF, but all the annotation/highlight etc. And AFAIR it ships with at least one book to try it on. When convinced, go pro (not camera ;)